# How can I use Python to pipe stdin/stdout to Perl script

Tags: python, pipe

This Python code pipes data through Perl script fine.

```
import subprocess
kw = {}
kw['executable'] = None
kw['shell'] = True
kw['stdin'] = None
kw['stdout'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw['stderr'] = subprocess.PIPE
args = ' '.join(['/usr/bin/perl','-w','/path/script.perl','<','/path/mydata'])
subproc = subprocess.Popen(args,**kw)
for line in iter(subproc.stdout.readline, ''):
    print line.rstrip().decode('UTF-8')
```

However, it requires that I first to save my buffers to a disk file (/path/mydata). It's cleaner to loop through the data in Python code and pass line-by-line to the subprocess like this:

```
import subprocess
kw = {}
kw['executable'] = '/usr/bin/perl'
kw['shell'] = False
kw['stderr'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw['stdin'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw['stdout'] = subprocess.PIPE
args = ['-w','/path/script.perl',]
subproc = subprocess.Popen(args,**kw)
f = codecs.open('/path/mydata','r','UTF-8')
for line in f:
    subproc.stdin.write('%s\n'%(line.strip().encode('UTF-8')))
    print line.strip()  ### code hangs after printing this ###
    for line in iter(subproc.stdout.readline, ''):
        print line.rstrip().decode('UTF-8')
subproc.terminate()
f.close()
```

The code hangs with the readline after sending the first line to the subprocess. I have other executables that use this exact same code perfectly.

My data files can be quite large (1.5 GB) Is there way to accomplish piping the data without saving to file? I don't want to re-write the perl script for compatibility with other systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks srgerg. I had also tried the threading solution. This solution alone, however, always hung. Both my previous code and srgerg's code were missing the final solution, Your tip gave me one last idea.

The final solution writes enough dummy data force the final valid lines from the buffer. To support this, I added code that tracks how many valid lines were written to stdin. The threaded loop opens the output file, saves the data, and breaks when the read lines equal the valid input lines. This solution ensures it reads and writes line-by-line for any size file.

```
def std_output(stdout,outfile=''):
    out = 0
    f = codecs.open(outfile,'w','UTF-8')
    for line in iter(stdout.readline, ''):
        f.write('%s\n'%(line.rstrip().decode('UTF-8')))
        out += 1
        if i == out: break
    stdout.close()
    f.close()

outfile = '/path/myout'
infile = '/path/mydata'

subproc = subprocess.Popen(args,**kw)
t = threading.Thread(target=std_output,args=[subproc.stdout,outfile])
t.daemon = True
t.start()

i = 0
f = codecs.open(infile,'r','UTF-8')
for line in f:
    subproc.stdin.write('%s\n'%(line.strip().encode('UTF-8')))
    i += 1
subproc.stdin.write('%s\n'%(' '*4096)) ### push dummy data ###
f.close()
t.join()
subproc.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is blocking at the line:

```
for line in iter(subproc.stdout.readline, ''):
```

because the only way this iteration can terminate is when EOF (end-of-file) is reached, which will happen when the subprocess terminates. You don't want to wait till the process terminates, however, you only want to wait till its finished processing the line that was sent to it.

Futhermore, you're encountering issues with buffering as Chris Morgan has already pointed out. Another [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python) discusses how you can do non-blocking reads with subprocess. I've hacked up a quick and dirty adaptation of the code from that question to your problem:

```
def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline, ''):
        queue.put(line)
    out.close()

kw = {}
kw['executable'] = '/usr/bin/perl'
kw['shell'] = False
kw['stderr'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw['stdin'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw['stdout'] = subprocess.PIPE
args = ['-w','/path/script.perl',]
subproc = subprocess.Popen(args, **kw)
f = codecs.open('/path/mydata','r','UTF-8')
q = Queue.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target = enqueue_output, args = (subproc.stdout, q))
t.daemon = True
t.start()
for line in f:
    subproc.stdin.write('%s\n'%(line.strip().encode('UTF-8')))
    print "Sent:", line.strip()  ### code hangs after printing this ###
    try:
        line = q.get_nowait()
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
    else:
        print "Received:", line.rstrip().decode('UTF-8')

subproc.terminate()
f.close()
```

It's quite likely that you'll need to make modifications to this code, but at least it doesn't block.

Answer (score 0):

See the warnings mentioned in the manual about using `Popen.stdin` and `Popen.stdout` (just above [`Popen.stdin`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin)):

> **Warning:** Use **`communicate()`** rather than **`.stdin.write`**, **`.stdout.read`** or **`.stderr.read`** to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

I realise that having a gigabyte-and-a-half string in memory all at once isn't very desirable, but using [`communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) is a way that *will* work, while as you've observed, once the OS pipe buffer fills up, the `stdin.write()` + `stdout.read()` way can become deadlocked.

Is using `communicate()` feasible for you?